# Convert FHIR model into FHIR JSON schema

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi

Let's say below is the FHIR model I have in C# for Patient resource.

```
    var pat = new Patient();        
    var name =  new HumanName().WithGiven("Christopher").WithGiven("C.H.").AndFamily("Parks");
    name.Prefix = new string[] { "Mr." };
    name.Use = HumanName.NameUse.Official;
```

How do I convert this into FHIR JSON Schema? Basically I want to serialize it. I am expecting the output like below

```
 {
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "xcda",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"></div>"
  },
  "active": true,
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Levin",
      "given": [
        "Henry"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1932-09-24",
  "managingOrganization": {
    "reference": "Organization/2.16.840.1.113883.19.5",
    "display": "Good Health Clinic"
  }
}
```

Also, I want to know is it possible to achieve this without using any FHIR external servers?

Comment: I believe that this is called 'serialising' it, not 'deserialising' it.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/parsing/poco-serialization.html

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It’s serialising into JSON. Thanks for bringing that up, I’ll edit it. Also, the link you have shared is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Were you wanting to convert this into JSON for a server implementation you're working on, or some other processing?

If it was for server processing, you might want to look at existing FHIR facade projects out there that might be able to expediate things (with FHIR input/output formatters etc)